# AWS lambda :Malformed Lambda proxy response

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

This is a typical issue while L**ambda sitting behind API gateway**. I've googled almost all the posts but still can't not figure out why it fails.

I've read the instruction on what the response should be look like 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-output-format 

It is looking for

```
{
    "isBase64Encoded": true|false,
    "statusCode": httpStatusCode,
    "headers": { "headerName": "headerValue", ... },
    "multiValueHeaders": { "headerName": ["headerValue", "headerValue2", ...], ... },
    "body": "..."
}
```

Here is the log of my test from API gateway console (**I have double checked make sure the name of fields are exactly the same**)

```
Thu Mar 19 10:07:58 UTC 2020 : Endpoint response body before transformations: "{\"statusCode\":200,\"body\":\"RESULTS\",\"isBase64Encoded\":false}"
Thu Mar 19 10:07:58 UTC 2020 : Execution failed due to configuration error: Malformed Lambda proxy response
Thu Mar 19 10:07:58 UTC 2020 : Method completed with status: 502
```

Can anyone help?

### EDIT

I've **removed "body"** from response and still get the same error. The following is the actual log

```
Thu Mar 19 23:29:54 UTC 2020 : Received response. Status: 200, Integration latency: 24 ms
Thu Mar 19 23:29:54 UTC 2020 : Endpoint response headers: {Date=Thu, 19 Mar 2020 23:29:54 GMT, Content-Type=application/json, Content-Length=48, Connection=keep-alive, x-amzn-RequestId=f2c2c752-a5e0-45e4-9ff0-d91826b51c7b, x-amzn-Remapped-Content-Length=0, X-Amz-Executed-Version=$LATEST, X-Amzn-Trace-Id=root=1-5e740072-46cee9045a56e04b8023816d;sampled=0}
Thu Mar 19 23:29:54 UTC 2020 : Endpoint response body before transformations: "{\"statusCode\":200,\"isBase64Encoded\":false}"
Thu Mar 19 23:29:54 UTC 2020 : Execution failed due to configuration error: Malformed Lambda proxy response
Thu Mar 19 23:29:54 UTC 2020 : Method completed with status: 502
```

The actual JSON response **catptured in java app & lambda** is

```
{"statusCode":200,"isBase64Encoded":false}
```

Comment: What is the code that generates this response?

Comment: @Marcin, it is a java class. I would assume that it has no impact since API gateway talks to Lambda, tries to parse Lambda's HTTP response?

Comment: What is the format of RESULTS here? Try removing body from your response to narrow down if it's related to RESULTS and test it.

Comment: @SurajBhatia, I was doing a simple test, the log I showed is the actual log, which means the content of body is a string "RESULT"

Comment: What does your actual JSON response look like?

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc, the actual JSON response, **captured in java app & Lambda log** are `{"statusCode":200,"isBase64Encoded":false}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After comparing to Node.js example, seems that it is to do with the handler.

When using a **RequestHandler**, the response is a **String**

```
public class MyLambda implements RequestHandler<Object, String> {
    @Override
    public String handleRequest(Object input, Context context) {
```

From API gateway, The response is showing as follows, note that the whole response is a **String**, and API gateway complains

```
Thu Mar 19 23:29:54 UTC 2020 : Endpoint response body before transformations: "{\"statusCode\":200,\"isBase64Encoded\":false}"
Thu Mar 19 23:29:54 UTC 2020 : Execution failed due to configuration error: Malformed Lambda proxy response
```

Changed that to **RequestStreamHandler** , the error is gone

```
public class APIgatewayTest implements RequestStreamHandler {
    @Override
    public void handleRequest(InputStream input, OutputStream output, Context context) throws IOException {
```

From API gateway, the response is as follows

```
Thu Apr 09 09:13:08 UTC 2020 : Endpoint response body before transformations: {"statusCode":200,"body":"\"Hello from Lambda!\""}
Thu Apr 09 09:13:08 UTC 2020 : Method response body after transformations: "Hello from Lambda!"
```